# Why Hive use file from other files under the partition table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a simple table in my `Hive`. It has only one partition:

```
show partitions hive_test;                       
OK
pt=20130805000000
Time taken: 0.124 seconds
```

But when I execute a simple query sql, it turns out to find the data file under folder `20130805000000`. Why doesn't it just use the file `20130805000000`?

sql:

```
SELECT buyer_id AS USER_ID from hive_test limit 1;
```

and this is the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: /group/myhive/test/hive/hive_test/pt=20130101000000/data
doesn't exist!
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPathWithLocations(DFSClient.java:1045)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:352)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ChRootedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(ChRootedFileSystem.java:270)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(ViewFileSystem.java:851)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.Yunti3FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(Yunti3FileSystem.java:349)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listLocatedStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:49)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:242)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:261)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1238)
```

And my question is why does hive try to find file "**/group/myhive/test/hive/hive_test/pt=20130101000000/data**", but not "**/group/myhive/test/hive/hive_test/pt=20130101000000/**"?

Comment: how did you create the partition? how did you insert the data to the partition? what is the directory/file tree under `/group/myhive/test/hive/hive_test/`? is the table defined `external`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting error because you have created partition over your hive table but not assigning partition name during select statement.

In Hive’s implementation of partitioning, data within a table is split across multiple partitions. Each partition corresponds to a particular value(s) of partition column(s) and is stored as a sub-directory within the table’s directory on HDFS. When the table is queried, where applicable, only the required partitions of the table are queried.

Please provide partition name in your select query or use your query like this:

```
select buyer_id AS USER_ID from hive_test where pt='20130805000000' limit 1;
```

Please see [Link](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/03/introduction-to-hive-partitioning/) to know more about hive partition.